# Cannot create a silly list of vectors with R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I can't understand why my data frame is treating stringsAsFactors. Can you please help?

I have:

```
>  frequentPatterns <- data.frame(
    pattern = character(),
    occurrences = numeric(),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

from the terminal I execute the following:

```
> obs2 = c()
> obs2$pattern <- "TAGCAA"
> obs2$count <- 5
> frquentPatterns <- rbind(frequentPatterns,obs2)
```

The first execution of the lines above loads the values into the data frame correctly. The SECOND run, it results in a warning

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "AGAAGCGAGATT") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I thought, and have read and read, that "stringsAsFactors = FALSE" should result in rbind not attempting to treat character values as factors. Am I smoking crack? Is that not what I have? what am I missing :) Thank you in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

`stringsAsFactors` only applies to the initial creation of the data frame. In addition to that misunderstanding there are other things you're doing wrong subsequently.

You start out creating `obs2` as if it were going to be a vector, but it's really just `NULL`. I think you'll find that adding an integer `count` has caused it to be coerced to a list (not a data frame). Don't `rbind` a data frame to a list. If you're going to do that (grow objects), (and you shouldn't grow objects), `rbind` two data frames:

```
> rbind(frequentPatterns,data.frame(pattern = 'AGAA',count = 5,stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  pattern count
1    AGAA     5
```

Finally, it is hardly necessary to be under the influence of drugs to make mistakes when writing code. I know this from personal experience. ;)

Comment: @saxman Apologies for all the edits; I wrote this very sloppily at first.

Comment: no issues....thank you for your help. I was able to resolve all these issues. Very new to 'R'. I like it, but it is a little different than Java/Node etc.